# Javascript - Add document.title to Twitter data text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Below is a Javascript to add a Twitter sharing button to a gallery lightbox script. The problem is that if the button gets clicked the Twitter text shows "document.title =(my_titles[set_position]);" instead of the actually document title. How to fix that?

```
social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com" data-text="document.title =(my_titles[set_position]);" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>' 
        }, my_settings);
```

Thanks.
Uli

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing `document.title` inside a string.

```
'<div class="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com"
    data-text="' + document.title + '=(my_titles[set_position]);" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
</div>'
```

Comment: that's still not correct, it'll print "foo =my_titles[set_position]);" as the title, where foo is document.title.

Comment: Yes. But I thought that's what he wanted to print. Otherwise he can just write `document.title` as `data-text`

Comment: why would he want to tweet the literal string "=(my_titles[set_position])" ?

Comment: Why would he write that in `data-text` then?

Comment: I guess since he has left out most of his other code, its difficult to decide what he wants

Answer (score 1):

```
social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com" data-text="' + document.title + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>' 
    }, my_settings);
```

Apparantly the script uses the text from the `data-text` attribute to find the text to display. So you need to input that before you generate the div. If you want anything other than the current document's title, change the `document.title` to what you want.